# How can I prevent my iOS app appstore page description from being indexed by search engines?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I cannot consider a business account / DBA as being an option for the contact information for my iTunes connect identity selling apps.

Is there any way to opt-out of search engine indexation of my app itunes appstore page (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app_name/app_id) which contain my full name?

Comment: @Annhill why do you want to opt out of search engine indexing

Comment: @Matt I simply don't want my name exposed on the web :)

Answer (score 3):

No, Apple controls the robots text for that website and publishes this information in the clear and allows search engines to crawl the App Store.

Unless you somehow worked through developer support to change the terms of the license agreement and how Apple runs their web pages, you’re stuck doing a name transfer to a DBA (doing business as entity) or forming a proper corporation to own the app in Apple’s eyes and be published openly as the author of the app(s).